# capturing and recording the video and audio at the same time

Tags: pi-3, audio, camera

I am new to Raspberry Pi field and I owe a Rsapberry pi 3 B in which i have installed a windows 10 IoT, am having camera along with mic and 2 outputs from camera one is USB and other is 3.5mm jack output. I need to capture video along with the voice how can i integrate both. Thank u in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, please read this and edit your 'question':  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not too hard to go on [google](https://www.google.com) and search "raspberry pi record video and audio". I found many results